# Running two databases on heroku with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, multiple-databases

I have two databases that my Django application needs access. One is a shared database owned by a separate app with the Django app only having read access. The second is entirely owned by the Django app.

For local development I am ok but I'm not sure how to configure things so that Heroku uses the second database.

Currently I have the shared database promoted to `DATABASE_URL` and the secondary database is at `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL`.

In my settings I have:

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'main_database_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }, 'secondary': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':  'secondary_database_name',                  
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    } 
}
```

Please ask any more questions if you need me to clarify.

Thanks!

In summary, my specific problem is: I don't know how to have Heroku use the `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL` as the "secondary" database.

---Edit----

At the bottom of `settings.py`:

```
# Configure Django App for Heroku.
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

This is where the connection is made between my app's default database and Heroku's `DATABASE_URL`. I still haven't solved the issue but after some troubleshooting help in the comments, I believe the answer will be found in there.

Comment: Did you try out a configuration that didn't work? What is the specific problem you're having?

Comment: @Blurp this is my current settings but I haven't deployed it. I'm not sure how to tell heroku to use `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL` as my secondary database.

Comment: Well, how are you telling it to use DATABASE_URL as the primary database? That's not obvious from the code you've shown.

Comment: @DanielRoseman correct. :) I'm not sure how that happens on Heroku. But I can confirm that the default database is using the DATABASE_URL on heroku. I would assume that since the 'default' database name is a reserved, special name on Django and DATABASE_URL is always the name of your main DB on heroku, that the two are automatically connected unless told to do otherwise. Probably in the django-heroku buildpack.

Comment: No. It's not automatic. You must have something in your settings file referring to DATABASE_URL; you should show it.

Comment: There is nothing in my settings referring to DATABASE_URL. Are you familiar with Heroku deployments?

Comment: Yes. The only way Django knows about your Heroku database is if you tell it. Often, that is done with `dj_database_url`; are you using that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman no I'm not. I see that in the Heroku documentation but I never did that. Is it possible that they included the functionality of `dj_database_url` in the default configuration of the heroku-python buildpack?

Comment: @DanielRoseman When I search the full repository the only hit for `dj-database-url` is in the `Pipfile.lock` and there is no hits for `DATABASE_URL` anywhere. I appreciate you trying to help me!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've found it. At the bottom of my settings I am using a package called `django-heroku`. 

`# Configure Django App for Heroku.
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())` I will look through that package to see how to use it for multiple databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working solution.

I have a `local_settings.py` file not tracked by version control. This contains the database settings for the developer's postgres instance.

**local_settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'main_database_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }, 'secondary': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':  'secondary_database_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Then in `settings.py` I try to import the `local_settings.py` file. If it doesn't exist, I use the `django_heroku` package to configure everything for Heroku. In my case, I need to pass the keyword argument `databases=False` since I want to do a more custom configuration for the databases.

**settings.py (only the relevant parts)**

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases
# These database settings are used for heroku deployments. They are overwritten with local_settings.py in development.
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }, 'secondary': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('SECONDARY_DATABASE_URL'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError as e:
    # Configure Django App for Heroku.
    import django_heroku
    django_heroku.settings(locals(), databases=False)
```

In order for this to work you would need to set the Heroku env variable `SECONDARY_DATABASE_NAME` to the url of your database.

To find out the URL of your secondary database run `heroku config -a your_app_name`. Copy the url and then set a new environment param in heroku by running

`heroku config:set SECONDARY_DATABASE_URL=postgres://xxxxxxx -a your_app_Name`

There are a lot of choices with how you would handle the ENV variables, I liked this because I can just set it in my staging and production environments and the same settings work for both.